# Arduino and Python: Serial.write not working

Tags: python, arduino

I have the following code on my arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
}


void loop() {
   while (!Serial.available());
   int x = Serial.readString().toInt();
   Serial.print(x+1);
}
```

Quite simple. So i have the following python code running as intended: I can pass a number and receive +1 as response

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)

def write_read(x):
    arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(1)
    data = arduino.readline()
    return data
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ") # Taking input from user
    print(num)
    value = write_read(num)
    print(value
```

I'm wondering why the following code does not work:

```
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)
arduino.write("4".encode()) # bytes("4", "utf-8) also not working
while True:
    print(arduino.readline())
    time.sleep(1)
```

This always gives me `b''` as response. But why? It seems like nothing is send to the arduino at all?

Comment: try `Serial.println(x+1);` in arduino code

Comment: only thing that worked was to wait for about two seconds before writing the first time

Comment: Arduino reboots on connection to serial... https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=566529.0